# iOS 12: UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist

Tags: ios, swift

My code works fine on iOS 11, but it crashes occasionally on iOS 12. The error I get is:

> Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:].
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received
>   layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:
>    {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}

I have a collection view showing several sections. I reload one of the sections when I get new data from the server. The code I use to reload the section is:

```
let attributes = calculateAttributesFrom(items)
layout.firstSectionAttributes = attributes                
collectionView.reloadSections([kFirstSectionIndex])
```

The number of items in a section is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if indexPath.section == kFirstSectionIndex {
        return layout.firstSectionAttributes.count
    } 
    ...
}
```

I use `layout.firstSectionAttributes.count` as the number of items in the sections. This means each attribute must have a corresponding cell. I guess this is related to `layout.invalidateLayout()`. I tried to add it before and after the reload, but it did not help.

Does anyone have any idea?

### Edit

It does not crash anymore after I replace `reloadSections` with `reloadData`. But I only want to reload one section instead of all of them.

Comment: Are you using a custom layout class?

Comment: @MarkusSchmid Yes

Comment: It would be worth a try to add all invalid item indexes (= indexes of items where the layout has changed or indexes of items that does not exist anymore) to the `invalidationContext` where `let invalidationContext = super.invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: newBounds)` in `override func invalidationContext(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext`. And take care of `override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?` and `override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool)`...

Comment: Hi @mark61, can you explain this approach a bit more. I am not using `prepare()` method in my custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class so I don't have cache. I wanted to remove all the existing data and recreate based on the new data provided(reduced number of rows)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: kFirstSectionIndex))
```